# Attributed Strings for UILabels in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I wanted to change the text of a label that says "hello world" such that "hello" is red, and "world" is blue. I'm doing this programmatically and obviously simplifying this example.

Is there a way to do this?

My alternative was to just create two uilabels, and set the attributes of each one accordingly, and then just add them together next to each other, but I thought it would be great if I could just assign the text of a label as per above instead.

By the way it doesn't have to be a `UILabel` as long as I can just render this text inside a `UITableView` row.

Thanks!

Comment: You just have to use `NSAttributedString`. There are plenty of tutorial in `Objective-C` that you could adapt into `Swift`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example on how to use `NSAttributedString`:

```
var resultString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello ", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
var worldString = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "World",
    attributes: [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(13.0)
    ]
)

resultString.appendAttributedString(worldString)
```

Then you can assign it to `UILabel`:

```
UILabel().attributedText = resultString
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help - quick question is there a way to also make "world string" bold? What would it look like?

Comment: Updated my answer with example. You can cmd+click on `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` in Xcode to explore other possible attributes.